# Format Integer or String into Long Integer (No scientific notation/Truncated/Rounded Numbers)

Tags: php, string, integer, number-formatting, long-integer

**Conclusion:** Marc B's solution is a 64 Bit, but for 32 Bit I'm not sure you can get the accuracy needed

**UPDATE #1:** 19 character length is the string/number max length

**UPDATE #2:** This kinda works but only if the number is in string format like this:

```
$number = "12345678901234567890";
```

if I pass it like this

```
$number = 12345678901234567890;
```

I get an warning:

> Warning: gmp_abs(): Unable to convert variable to GMP - wrong type

Updated Class

```
class StringToInteger {
    public static function getInteger($number) {
        //return sprintf('%.0f', $number);
    //$number = sprintf('%d', $number);
    $number = gmp_abs($number);
    return gmp_strval($number);
    }
}
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION BELOW:**

I have some data being passed either as a string or integer (Think Phone Number but longer), most of the data is just a long number like this:

```
1234567890123456789
```

But sometimes it comes like this

```
123-456-789-012-345-678-9 // could be other non numeric characters as well
```

Using the below functions doesn't give the desired results

```
class StringToInteger {
    public static function getInteger($number) {
        return number_format($number, 0, '.', '');
    }
}

class NumericOnly {
    public static function formatNumber($number) {
        return preg_replace("/[^\d]/", "", $number); 
    }
}
```

Pass as numeric:

```
$number = 1234567890123456789;
// output: 1.23456789012E+18 can't use this
echo "Number: {$number}\n"; 

// Where did my number go? truncated/rounded?
// output: 12345678901218 can't use this
echo "Numeric Only: ".NumericOnly::formatNumber($number)."\n"; 

// Where did my number go? truncated?
// output: 1234567890123456768 can't use this
echo "String To Integer: ".StringToInteger::getInteger($number)."\n";
```

Pass as string:

```
$string = '1234567890123456789';
// output: 1234567890123456789
echo "String Number: {$string}\n"; 

// Works
// output: 1234567890123456789
echo "String Numeric Only: ".NumericOnly::formatNumber($string)."\n"; 

// Where did my number go? truncated?
// output: 1234567890123456768 can't use this
echo "String To Integer: ".StringToInteger::getInteger($string)."\n"; 

// After Conversion, truncated?
// output: 1234567890123456768 can't use this
echo "After String To Integer: ";
echo StringToInteger::getInteger(NumericOnly::formatNumber($string))."\n";
```

Alpha Numeric

```
$string = '123-456-789-012-345-678-9';
// output: 123-456-789-012-345-678-9 can't use this
echo "String Number: {$string}\n"; 

// Works
// output: 1234567890123456789
echo "String Numeric Only: ".NumericOnly::formatNumber($string)."\n"; 


// After Conversion, truncated?
// output: 1234567890123456768 can't use this
echo "After String To Integer: ";
echo StringToInteger::getInteger(NumericOnly::formatNumber($string))."\n";
```

Any ideas on how to get a Long Integer (The full correct number)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest integer that can be represented in a 64bit PHP install, compared to your number:

```
   9,223,372,036,854,775,808 - largest possible signed 64bit integer
  12,345,678,901,234,567,890 - your number
```

since you're exceeding the maximum number size, you can't expect to get useful results without using something like [bcmath](http://php.net/bcmath)/[GMP](http://php.net/gmp).

Comment: sorry the max length is 19, thanks for pointing this out. It has been fixed. Same issue as the number gets truncated

Comment: Looking at GMP I can use $number = gmp_abs($number); return gmp_strval($number); but it only works in it's in a string format. Any thoughts on passing a double/int ?